# Displaying Live Incoming Smartphone Images with Ushahidi on Map?

Tags: web-mapping, ushahidi, crowdsourcing

I have not yet used [Ushahidi](http://www.ushahidi.com/) and I could not find the answer on their website to my question.

I wish to do the following:

1. setup an Ushahidi server/map,
2. go outside to make photos with my Android/iPhone smartphone
3. upload these photos to Ushahidi which should be saved in a database
4. display the photos on the map according to the coordinates. Also few lines of comments would be nice.

When I now visit my site and open the map, I would like to see some dots (actual position of an entry/uploaded image). By double clicking on the dot, the original uploaded image+comments should be displayed(pop up).

Is this possible with Ushahidi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily set up your own Ushahidi deployment at [Crowdmap](https://crowdmap.com/). It's just a matter of filling out your profile and naming your deployment.

> Crowdmap is designed and built by the people behind Ushahidi, a
>   platform that was originally built to crowdsource crisis information.
>   As the platform has evolved, so have its uses. Crowdmap allows you to
>   set up your own map of Ushahidi without having to install it on your
>   own web server

Crowdmap also has an Android app called [Crowdmap Checkins](http://blog.ushahidi.com/index.php/2011/03/10/checkins-ci-experimental-functionality/) which you can use to take photos and link them to the coordinates. They can then be visualized on the map if I'm not mistaken.

[image]

Good luck on your project :)